# potty... what am I doing wrong

Tags: toddler, potty-training

My daughter is one years old I've been putting her on the potty 1st I would put her on the big toilet, and realized she didn't like it. now she sits on the potty.some days she goes and somedays she doesn't. What am I doing wrong? And she likes to drink a lot of water and juice please help. I let her sit for about 35 minutes in the morning noon and night

Comment: Definitely sounds like too early.  My 21 month old wants to go like big brother, and has once gone, but mostly still doesn't have the physical stuff - it's not just mental, it's physically being able to go on purpose.

Answer (score 6):

You may simply be too soon.  Usually 22 to 30 months is considered the "standard" age.  With Our first daughter, we tried to "push it", and it turned into a horrible, long drawn out mess.  On the flip side, we didn't force the issue with our second daughter.  Then a few days before Preschool, we realized she hadn't yet learned.

Our oldest said "No Problem Mommy." She explained it all to her sister, and she was potty-trained in a day.  So, when your child is ready, it will be a lot easier.  What you are doing now is fine, so that she can get used to it, but my advice is be patient.  She will learn when she is ready.

Comment: I agree. I would go a bit further and say that starting at twelve months might even be disadvantageous; it frustrates mom, and the child is disappointing mom for something she can't yet control.

Comment: Yes. Good point. I don't think having her sit on her potty chair will hurt, as long as the only expectation is for her to get used to sitting on it.  Beyond that, it does cause issues.  For us,  the result was our daughter being potty trained at 27 months, after starting at 13..... over a year of training.  Ugh!  Then,  our second was trained at 25 months,  over the course of ONE day. ..

Answer (score 0):

35 minutes of sitting is WAY too much for a 1 year old, I wouldn't even do that to a 10 year old.  You can't force it.  The way to do it is make the child excited about the potty, read potty books with her, and give rewards, NEVER punishments.  Sitting for 35 minutes is a punishment.  This is a happy time to learn new things about life, not boot camp.  Be calm and pleasant about it.

There is nothing wrong with potty training very young if you do it well, the time you put into it will be well worth it when you no longer have to change diapers, and it's better for the environment to have a potty trained 1 year old, rather than continuing to use diapers for another 2 years.

Comment: Many children that age enjoy sitting on the potty for long periods of time.  My three year old happily sits that long (and he's fully trained).  He just likes being alone by himself reading a book or playing with the iPad.